# mtu 9000 issues only on tcp and not icmp possible?

Tags: networking, tcp, ethernet, icmp

I have a connection between two datacenters and rsync between them stalls often. I think it is related to the mtu 9000 (I actualy set it to 8900 because of some possible vlan use)

I have the impression that the icmp mtu 8900 is working, but that tcp traffic is having sometimes problems with big frames.

Has any one experienced something similar? And how do you test MTU 8900 with just a tcp test?

PS. I don't have control over this connection

Comment: Jumbo frames are only supposed to be used in a network where all the NICs are operating at jumbo frames, and mostly for a LAN network.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the MTU to see if the issue goes away? And/or have you tried doing a tcpdump on both sides when the issue is occurring to see if packets are making it through?

Comment: On a few *NIXes (Linux, some *BSD) it should even be possible to lower the MSS (which usually derives from MTU) for TCP without changing the jumbo frame settings: with iptables + TCPMSS on Linux, and pf + scrub max-mss on *BSD.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, it is configured like this

Comment: @Patrick I indeed tried lower MTU's and had much better results. (But I don't want to downgrade all connections because of one not working properly

Comment: @A.B At the moment I would like to just know/proof what is going wrong.

Comment: You still should do what Patrick suggested: capture with tcpdump. here's a link talking about PMTUD, MTU, MSS (ignore the tunnel part): https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/generic-routing-encapsulation-gre/25885-pmtud-ipfrag.html#anc3

Comment: @f1outsourcing If dropping the MTU fixed it, then yes, you should definitely do a packet capture. This smells like you have something in the mix which is dropping ICMP packets, which are critical to the operation of networks, especially when you have oversized frames.